# Running the Black formatter from Docker with a Makefile command

Tags: python, git, docker, makefile, python-black

Rather than installing Black on my local machine, I'm experimenting with running Black (installed from requirements.txt) from a Docker container. I'm looking to add a Makefile command to format modified files. This is what I've come up with so far, which is run with `make format`:

```
# formats any files which differ from the point at which the current branch (2) forked from master (1)
# ____1_____________ master
#     \__________ dev
#          \_________2 current_branch
diff_files := $(shell git diff $(git merge-base --fork-point master) --name-only -- "*.py")
format:
    docker-compose run --rm api black $(diff_files)
```

This finds the point at which the current branch forked from master

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base#_operation_modes:

```
git merge-base --fork-point master
```

And this returns the files names returned from the diff with the .py extension (.py filter might be overkill?)

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_description

```
--name-only -- "*.py"
```

Would love to hear some feedback, or any examples of similar setups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dollar signs are significant to make: they introduce variables.  If you want to pass a dollar sign to a shell script, say within a `$(shell ..)` function, you need to escape them by writing them as `$$`:

```
diff_files := $(shell git diff $$(git merge-base --fork-point master) --name-only -- "*.py")
```

Otherwise, make thinks that `$(git merge-base --fork-point master)` is a long and very odd-looking make variable, and all make variables that are not defined are evaluated to the empty string.

Comment: Since the dollar signs are being used for command substitutions and not to reference variables, isn't escaping them with $$ incorrect? I've tested the format target as defined in my original question and it seems to work without any issues, am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer if you want a make variable or function you use single `$` (don't escape it).  If you want to pass the value to the shell (for example, as a command substitution) you have to escape it from make and use `$$`.  The way you have it written, the shell is running the command `git diff --name-only -- "*.py"`.  Maybe that is actually working for you so it seems OK.  But, you are absolutely _not_ running the `git merge-base` command at all in your makefile.